# Timestamp error in inserting sql query

Tags: java, sql

I am reading  input from some files using java which also includes timestamp values.And had created a table as follows

```
 CREATE TABLE 
      user_profile (text varchar(1000),
      name varchar(1000),
      time datetime, 
      PRIMARY KEY (text,name));
```

After that i inserted values for text,name and  time(for time value is "2014-05-26 10:28:04.0").
After checking table using select statement output shown as

```
Name     Text     Time
rooney   manu     2014-05-26 00:00:00.0
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What SQL DB are you using? Which jdbc driver and maybe you can show us your code, which inserts the values?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the `insert` and `select` statements that you used.  Also, you should tag the question with the particular database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Di u checked this link why u were googling the problem????

If not check this link it might have the solution to ur problem:

[https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48704/mysql-5-6-datetime-incorrect-datetime-value-2013-08-25t1700000000-with-er]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your input value might not be in a text format of the date that your database is expecting.  In a lot of the older parsing routines, the parser parses as much as possible before halting the parsing operation.  See `Integer.parse(...` and others for examples.

My guess is that your database managed to parse out the date, but since it's not an ISO format date, it stopped at the space.  ISO format dates with time extensions are not separated by spaces, but by the letter 'T' as so

```
2014-05-26T10:28:04
```

However, this is not really a fully specified time, you need to also include a timezone offeset, so a full ISO8601 date typically looks like

```
2014-05-26T10:28:04Z
```

for UTC or

```
2014-05-26T10:28:04+06:00
```

with a +6 hour timezone offset